# Moving Image from top to bottom in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, move

I have to move "Ant image" from top to bottom. On touch, Ant Image should destroy.This logic is similar to ant smasher application.

Currently I have taken Image view in relative layout and I am moving the Image from top to bottom. For Image view I am setting ant bitmap. Currently I am able to move image.

am  I going in right direction? I feel there could be better approach than this.

Is it correct to take ImageView for ant for moving?

Is it correct to take relative layout in this scenario?

Kindly suggest if there is better alternative solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to take ImageView for ant for moving?

### Yes

> Is it correct to take relative layout in this scenario?

**Yes**, But it can cause problem when you remove ant view as all views on screen are placed relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can work in LinearLayout too..would be more simple and helpful when the ant is removed..or for adding more ants..